# Path traversal using hash extension attack

Tags: hash, php, md5, url, directory-traversal

I'm trying to write a PoC for path traversal using hash extension attack on a PHP site.
My obstacle is in specifying an acceptable string. The vulnerability is in in the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/download.php?file=file.txt&hash=[the valid md5 hash]
```

I'm trying to print out `/etc/passwd` using this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/download.php?file=file.txt��/../../../etc/passwd&hash=[extended valid hash]
```

The backend first checks whether the provided MD5 is valid and then prints out the requested file. I'm using the PHP functions `fopen` and `fread` for that.

I'm able to create valid hashes for arbitrary strings but PHP fails with the following error:

> **Warning**: `fopen()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in `/var/www/html/download.php`

**Note:** The characters `��` in the URL are due to the MD5 padding of the hash extension.

Comment: Do you have the php code ? The information you gave isn't enough if you have the code then put it in pastebin or zip file and link it here

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116117)

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what isn't clear about my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [PHP 5.3.4](https://secure.php.net/releases/5_3_4.php), an error is thrown if a path contains a null byte.